# Prove that every solution of an ODE system converges to some point

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes

> Suppose $p(t)>2$ and is continuous for all $t\in\Bbb R$, 
>   $$x'=2y,\\ y'=-2x-p(t)y^3,$$ prove that for each solution $(x(t),y(t))$ there exists a point $(x^*,0)$ to which it converges.

I guess the most probable approach is [Lyapunov stability theory](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_stability), which is within the range of my ODE course. But this is a non-autonomous system (with time-varying input $p(t)$), and all I have learned from class is criteria for stability for autonomous systems.

It seems kinda obvious that $x^*$ is relevant to $p(t)$, but I have trouble  even proving the *existence* of a singular point $(x^*,0)$ for this system, let alone dealing with it analytically.

The case $p(t)\equiv\text{const}$ is easy, with $(0,0)$ apparently being the only singular point which is also apparently globally Lyapunov asymptotically stable on $\Bbb R^2$, and hence globally attracting (meaning all solutions converge to this singular point.)

But for a time-varying input it is entirely different. Maybe I'll need a non-autonomous version of criterion for Lyapunov stability? But since this is beyond my course's level I think it there must be some more elementary alternatives. I'd be very grateful if anybody can provide me with one. (Of course if using non-autonomous versions can't be helped I would also be glad to learn about such tricks as long as they are effective.)

---

*EDIT* Terribly sorry. I made a mistake. $(x^*,0)$ may be dependent upon the solution (or the initial condition).

Comment: Note that $x(t) \equiv y(t) \equiv 0$ is still a solution in the non-autonomous case.

Comment: @Evgeny yeah. But I virtually have no idea why each solution is convergent. (BTW do you come from where Lyapunov lived haha

Comment: I might suspect that they want you to find Lyapunov function for autonomous case and check what happens if you use it for non-autonomous system. Kind of 'using non-autonomous version of Lyapunov theorem without telling it explicitly' :)

Comment: As far as I see, linearization has pair or purely imaginary eigenvalues, so Lyapunov First Thm isn't applicable... Function $V(x, y) = x^2+y^2$ seems to be a nice candidate, but it requires few workarounds.

Comment: @Evgeny sorry. My fallacy. You are right, the radius square function seem to cancel the cross term and leave only $-py^4$. Then one can apply [Krasovski-Barbasin criterion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Krasovskii%E2%80%93LaSalle_principle&redirect=no) to claim asymptotic stability. However it's applicable only for autonomous systems.

Comment: Well, to some extent you are right :) but if you were told about extended phase space, then you can draw new picture: $(0, 0, t)$ is a line in 3dimensional extended phase space which corresponds to equilibrium point of autonomous system. Level sets of $V(x, y) = x^2+y^2$ are cylinders that surround $(0, 0, t)$. If you take a look at vector field at any cylinder it is either tangent to it or "goes inside". And thus all trajectories come closer and closer to this line.

Comment: @Evgeny Ok so they do. The $t$ line is just like a "focus" to some extent. I think this method is convincing, but how about using the fact $p>2$? I can't figure out what's special about $2$, I think $1$ or even $0$ will just be fine, isn't it? (In fact based on your approach the only thing remaining to be solved is to prove that there doesn't exist something like a *limit cycle* around the time line.

Comment: @Evgeny I'm sorry I made a mistake. The convergence point might be solution-dependent. See edit.

Comment: This condition $p(t) > 2$ was bugging me too. I thought that maybe if we find more clever Lyapunov function for constant case, we'll get condition this condition for $p$. But no, we are still using $V(x, y) = x^2+y^2$ and I have no better idea. Also I understand that it's kinda strange that we still see only line $(0, 0, t)$ as a candidate for limit set, but our "Lyapunov" functions suggests it quite convincing.

Comment: Speaking about limit cycle, it is impossible to have them in extended phase space. Recall that equations of motion in extended phase space are: $$\dot{x} = 2y$$ $$\dot{y} = -2x - p(\tau) y^3$$ $$\dot{\tau} = 1.$$ If you had a closed trajectory, you would have $\tau(0) = \tau(T)$ and somewhere $\dot{tau}$ should be zero, but it is nowhere zero in extended phase space. So, no limit cycles.

Comment: @Evgeny my prof hinted me: 1) show that $V(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ converges (which we already solved); 2) show that $y(t)$ converges using $V'=-2py^4$.  I think we might need to show that if $y$ doesn't converge then $\int_0^\infty py^4 ds$ diverges, contradicting the fact that $V\ge 0$. So I desperately need the uniform continuity of $py^4$, but that seems hard to get.

Comment: @Evgeny pardon my poor wording. I was referring to a cycle in the phase space to which the trajectory converges, or a *limit cylinder* in the extended phase space.

Comment: Frankly speaking, I don't understand 2nd hint of your professor.... My reasoning stays the same: we showed that for any cylinder vector field is either pointing inside or tangent to it. Then I use [this theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bony%E2%80%93Brezis_theorem) to conclude that even if we have tangency, trajectory still goes inside at this point. But if it goes inside at moment $t_0$, then for all $t > t_0$ holds $V(t) < V(t_0)$. And that's why I'm concluding that $V(x, y)$ goes to zero and tajectory comes closer and closer to $(0, 0, t))$.

Comment: I understand that using this theorem might seem to be a little overkill, though it always perfectly supports intuition about going in or out through the boundary of set...

Comment: @Evgeny I think he means: in general  integral curve going   inside seems to be insufficient for saying it goes to origin. The particle may reside near a point on x axis for ever. However $y(t)$ must converge to zero anyhow.

Comment: Well, this interpretation makes sense. However, trajectory not just goes inside *one* cylinder: it goes inside of *any* cylinder, surrounding $\tau$-axis. By the way, have you tried simulations? Do they give any insight?

Comment: @Evgeny not yet. I'm not with my computer now. (Yeah it does go inside any cylinder that it can *reach*, but there may be one that it will never reach, like a limit cylinder. )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multiplying the second equation by $y$ and using the first equation we have
$$y\dot{y}=-2xy-p(t)y^4=-x\dot{x}-p(t)y^4$$
i.e. as correctly pointed in the comments by @Evgeny 
$$\frac{d}{dt}[x^2+y^2]=-2p(t)y^4\leq -4 y^4$$

Thus $x,y$ are bounded and the Lyapunov-like function $V=x^2+y^2$ is decreasing and lower bounded (from zero). Hence, $V$ converges to some constant $V_{\infty}\geq 0$. If we integrate the above inequality over $[0,\infty)$ we obtain
$$V_{\infty}-V(0)\leq -4\int_0^{\infty}{y^4(s)ds}$$
which yields
$$\int_0^{\infty}{y^4(s)ds}\leq \frac{1}{4}V(0)$$

If we assume a **bounded** $p(t)$ then the boundedness of $x,y$ and the state equations result in the boundedness of $\dot{x},\dot{y}$.

**A continuous differentiable function with bounded derivative is uniformly continuous.**

You can use  now **Barbalat's lemma** to prove convergence. Barbalat's lemma states that if

i) $\int_0^{\infty}{\phi(t)dt}$ exists and is finite and

ii) $\phi(\cdot)$ is uniformly continuous

then $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\phi(t)= 0$.

From Barbalat lemma we then have that $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}y(t)=0$ and since $V$ converges there also exists some $x^*$  (with $V_{\infty}={x^*}^2$) such that $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}x(t)=x^*$.

**Edit to remove the upper bounded $p(t)$ restriction:** I will prove now a variation of Barbalat lemma that does not need uniform continuity of $\phi(\cdot)$ but only an upper bounded derivative.

**Barbalat lemma variation:** Let $\phi:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}_+$ continuous differentiable nonnegative function. If

i) $\int_0^{\infty}{\phi(t)dt}$ exists and is finite and

ii) $\dot{\phi}(\cdot)$ is upper bounded

then $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\phi(t)= 0$.

**Proof:** The proof uses a contradiction argument. Assume the opposite, then there exists a constant $k_1>0$ and a sequence of times $\{T_i\}$ with $\lim_{i\rightarrow\infty}T_i=\infty$ such that 
$$\phi(T_i)\geq k_1$$
For $t\leq T_i$ we have from the **mean value theorem** that
$$\phi(t)=\phi(T_i)-\dot{\phi}(\theta t +(1-\theta)T_i)(T_i-t)$$
for some $\theta\in(0,1)$. Since $\dot{\phi}$ is upper bounded there exists some $c$ such that $\dot{\phi}(t)\leq c$ for all $t\geq 0$ and
$$\phi(t)\geq \phi(T_i)-c(T_i-t)\qquad \forall t\leq T_i$$
From the above relationship we have that 
$$\phi(t)\geq \frac{k_1}{2}\qquad \forall t\in\left[T_i-\frac{k_1}{2|c|},T_i\right]$$ 
Therefore
$$\int_{T_i-\frac{k_1}{2|c|}}^{T_i}{\phi(t)dt}\geq \frac{k_1^2}{4|c|} $$
Thus $\int_0^{t}{\phi(\tau)d\tau}$ cannot converge to a finite limit as $t\rightarrow \infty$ which is the desired contradiction.

In our example  $\phi(t):=y^4$ and its **derivative is upper bounded** since
$$\dot{\phi}(t)=4y^3\dot{y}=-8xy^3-4p(t)y^6\leq -8xy^3$$
and $x,y$ are bounded. The proposed variation of Barbalat lemma yields now the desired $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}y(t)=0$. This completes the proof and indeed **there is no need for an upper bound of $p(t)$**.

Comment: Point is, we don't know that $p$ is bounded.

Comment: @Vim I have edited my answer to consider the general case. The proof is completed by a modification of Barbalat lemma.