# Proving that $y(t)\to0$ given a dynamical system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Consider a nonlinear system of the form

$$\dot{y}(t)=p(y(t)) + u(t)$$

where

$$p(q) = a_kq^k+a_{k-1}q^{k-1}+\ldots+a_1q$$
$$u(t) = -\left(\alpha_ky(t)^k+\ldots+\alpha_1y(t)\right)-y(t)$$

with $\dot{\alpha}_i=y(t)^{i+1}$ for $i=1,\ldots, k$. It can be shown that

$$\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t}\left[\frac12\left(y(t)^2+\sum_{i=1}^k(a_i-\alpha_i)^2\right)\right]=-y(t)^2\tag{1}$$

Using this information, show that $y(t)\to0$ as $t\to\infty$. [Hint: Use first principles.]

---

So I must show that solution $y(t)=0$ is asymptotically stable. Originally I tried Lyapunov theory but that didn't work (and is advised against). But how would I show this from first principles? I need to show that

$$\lim_{t\to\infty} y(t)=0$$

from the information given. How on earth would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These type of problems arise in **adaptive control** where the controller uses estimations (the $\alpha_i$ in your case) of the unknown system parameters ($a_i$ in the example). The convergence analysis follows from the so called **Barbalat lemma** which states the following:

If $f$ is uniformly continuous and the integral $\int_0^{\infty}{f(s)ds}$ exists and is finite then $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}f(t)=0$.

In the above example let us define 
$$S:=\frac{1}{2}y^2+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^k{(a_i-\alpha_i)^2}$$
You have proved that
$$\dot{S}\leq -y^2\leq 0\qquad\qquad (1)$$
i.e. $S$ is decreasing and lower bounded from zero and therefore it converges i.e. there exists some $S_{\infty}\geq 0$ such that $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}S(t)=S_{\infty}$. Integrating (1) over $[0,\infty)$ we obtain
$$S_{\infty}-S(0)\leq -\int_0^{\infty}{y^2(t)dt}$$
Hence, for function $f(t)=y^2(t)$ the integral $\int_0^{\infty}{f(s)ds}$ exists and is finite. If we also prove that $f$ is uniformly continuous then from Barbalat's lemma the desired property $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}f(t)=0$ is directly obtained.

The boundedness of $S$ implies the boundedness of $y$ and $\alpha_i$ ($i=1,\ldots,k$). Thus, $u$ is bounded (see the definition of $u$) and therefore from the original equation describing the system dynamics, the derivative $\dot{y}$ is also bounded. Since every differentiable function with bounded derivative is uniformly continuous, $\dot{y}\in\mathcal{L}_{\infty}$ implies $y$ is uniformly continuous which combined with $y\in\mathcal{L}_{2}$ yields the desired conclusion.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the answer, is there any way to answer this without the Barbalat lemma, as this hasn't been covered in my course.

Comment: @user2850514 Well, you can prove Barbalat's lemma from first principles. The proof is a simple contradiction argument. See for example my answer to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1599745/prove-that-every-solution-of-an-ode-system-converges-to-some-point/1601504#1601504